# What's the purpose of empty tags in HTML?

Tags: jsx

Analyzing the code of an open-source web application built with [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/), I encountered this code block:

```
const three = <h3 className="big-heading">subtitle</h3>;
  const four = (
    <>
      <p>
        some text
      </p>
    </>
  );
```

There's a particular reason to have those empty tags around `<p>` tag? Looks to me that is caused by the automatic generation of code since, removing it, doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax has no meaning in HTML, but you don't have HTML there. That is JSX.

It is the [short syntax for fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) which allow you to bundle multiple elements together.

It contains a single element (a paragraph) so it is pointless in this specific case.